# Plotting a normpdf in 3D over scatter plot/linear regression

Tags: matlab, gnuplot

I have a set of data `x(1000,2)`,

```
2   18.1199158925616
3   9.56472607516328
7   34.3629828698699
4   30.9865760010538
7   54.4869549747429
8   54.7696742935546
2   1.45832407805944
3   15.4231700658276
8   57.0479651194063
1   5.34909555648445
2   11.5593766410445
2   17.4392978010484
6   25.4072607558367
4   15.1248062077068
2   13.2035176450795
7   33.2507069131440
5   21.6859046133920
3   18.4458236149053
1   0.824962982951128
8   46.6322862041701
8   43.6889420657037
2   17.0930689315346
3   13.9754117410459
2   1.99260423380962
11  86.3172411757665
8   50.6244869641866
1   1.16602336459361
2   12.6604166373800
2   17.4519078987572
5   27.4799515521804
```

which I have plotted `plot(x(:,1),x(:,2),'*r');`in scatter form:
[image]

but would like to have something like below using `normpdf` for selected values of x(:,1):
[image]

To find values in `x(:,2)` column corresponding to `x(:,1)==3`:

```
[x3]=x(find(x(:,1)==3),2);
mu=mean(x3);
sig=std(x3);
Y=normpdf(x3,mu,sig);

figure('color',[1,1,1]);
hhh=plot3(3*ones(length(xi)),x(find(x(:,1)==3),2),Y,'-r')
p = polyfit(x(:,1),x(:,2),1);
plin=plot(x(:,1),polyval(p,x(:,1)),'-b');
```

[image: my version looks pants]
but how do I get the red dotted pdf to be a smooth curve as '-r' gives me zig-zag lines. Do I have to order the data in some way?
Also how do I get the red dots in the center of the normal curve down to the blue line? 
And perhaps most importantly, as a well informed reader would you like to see this type of plot or perhaps something else less fancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a sorting of the `x`-values should get you the red curve. Also you do not need `find()` here. I have not tested the code, but these changes should work:

```
[x3]=sort(x(x(:,1)==3,2));
mu=mean(x3);
sig=std(x3);
Y=normpdf(x3,mu,sig);

figure('color',[1,1,1]);
hhh=plot3(3*ones(length(xi)),x3,Y,'-r')
p = polyfit(x(:,1),x(:,2),1);
plin=plot(x(:,1),polyval(p,x(:,1)),'-b');
```

As for the value of such a plot, I would guess that it will be quite cluttered. But I guess it could be used to give a general view of the distribution of the data.

Comment: Nice! Any ideas about the dotted lines down from the apex of the normal curves?

Comment: You want to plot a dotted line from `(3,mean,0)` to `(3,mean,normpdf(mean,mu,sigma)` so something like
`plot3([3,3],[mu mu],[0 normpdf(mu,mu,sig)],'--')` should do the trick.